# PYTHONPATH environment variable...how do I make every subdirectory afterwards?

Tags: python, linux, unix, environment-variables

I currently do this:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/$USER:/home/$USER/respository:/home/$USER/repository/python-stuff
```

How can I make it so that the PYTHONPATH can include everything subdirectory?

```
PYTHONPATH = /home/$USER/....and-all-subdirectories
```

Comment: This sounds like a terrible plan.  It makes some kinds of testing nearly impossible because every python file -- in a random order -- will be on the `PYTHONPATH`.  Please describe why you think this is helpful.  What problem do you have?  What are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: I, for one, want to do this because I have various single-file standalone modules I wrote for odds-and-ends calculations, like "moon_orbit_calculations.py", "spherical_geometry_calculations.py", etc. etc. There are a lot of these, so I made subdirectories to organize them. I want to add them all to the path so I can import them, but don't want to type in and keep updating all the subdirectory names. (My multi-file packages are elsewhere on the disc, not affected by this.) Is that unreasonable? Is there another way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to have on `sys.path` two paths one of which is the parent of the other -- assuming the sub-directory one contains an `__init__.py` file to mark it as a package, of course.  If only the parent directory is in the path (and `$PYTHONPATH` is part of what `sys.path` is initialized with), modules in the subdirectory can be imported from the package, i.e., through just one filesystem path, avoiding the risk of a single module being imported under many distinct guises.

So why don't you just put `__init__.py` files in all subdirectories that need it, and use package imports?

While I think your request is a bad idea, it's certainly doable -- the Unix `find` command can easily list all subdirectories of a directory, one per line (`find . -type d`), and you can easily glue the lines together e.g. by piping find's output to `tr '\n' :`.

Comment: Thanks Alex Martelli! You need to write more books.

Comment: Yes I do, but finding the time and energy is hard;-).

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
import os
import sys

all_modules = {} #keeps track of the module names

def discoverModules():
    ''' Populates a dictionary holding every module name in the directory tree that this file is run '''    
    global all_modules

    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
        # Advanced usage:
        # editing the 'dirnames' list will stop os.walk() from recursing into there.
        if '.git' in dirnames:
            # don't go into any .git directories.
            dirnames.remove('.git')

        # save path to all subdirectories in the sys.path so we can easily access them:
        for subdirname in dirnames:                    
            name = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname) # complete directory path
            sys.path.append(name) # add every entry to the sys.path for easy import

        # save path to all filenames:
        for filename in filenames:        
            # we want to save all the .py modules, but nothing else:
            if '.py' in filename and '.pyc' not in filename and '__init__' not in filename:
                moduleName = '' #this will hold the final module name

                # If on Mac or Linux system:
                if str(os.name) == 'posix': 
                    for element in dirname.split('\/'): # for each folder in the traversal
                        if element is not '.': # the first element is always a '.', so remove it
                            moduleName += element + '.' # add a '.' between each folder

                # If on windoze system:
                elif str(os.name) == 'nt': 
                    for element in dirname.split('\\'): # for each folder in the traversal
                        if element is not '.': # the first element is always a '.', so remove it
                            moduleName += element + '.' # add a '.' between each folder

                # Important to use rstrip, rather than strip. If you use strip, it will remove '.', 'p', and 'y' instead of just '.py'
                moduleName += filename.rstrip('.py') # finally, add the filename of the module to the name, minus the '.py' extension            
                all_modules[str(filename.rstrip('.py'))] = moduleName # add complete module name to the list of modules
    print 'Discovering Modules...Complete!'
    print 'Discovered ' + str(len(all_modules)) + ' Modules.'
```